# Do routers detect and adapt to different quality Ethernet cables?

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable

I'm running a long (30 meter) Ethernet cable between two routers. Although both routers have [GigE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet) ports, all I have at the moment is [Cat3 cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_3_cable), which maxes out at 10Mb/s (especially over that long a cable).

If I use a substandard cable type that can't handle gigabit speeds, will the router(s) detect this and adapt to it, or will I have errors or a complete lack of connectivity? And, if the routers would NOT detect this problem, how would I detect it (assuming I didn't know the quality of the cable)?

Comment: In the real world this doesn't always work as expected, especially in consumer grade equipment, My recommendation would be to only connect pins 1,2,3,6 and for a 100Mb/s connection. Legitimate Cat-3 should handle 100Mb/s just fine, I've done it literally hundreds of times.

Answer (score 2):

The router will use what it has and lower the speeds accordingly. It does not adapt in the sense that it understands substandard cable. It simply send out packets and accepts any errors it get back (how TCP/IP works).

It is always better to use top notch quality cable at least CAT5e or better.  I have a CAT5e cable from the basement through to the second floor which works fine. I have CAT6 cables connecting all my network gear on the network shelf to ensure maximum performance between devices.

Answer (score 1):

Way too complicated for me to explain in full - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_twisted_pair - but basically the devices at each end can recognise by either number of connected wires in the cable or by handshake to establish a maximum qualified speed.

Everything will then be limited to that speed. Cat3 maxes out at 10Mb/s, so that is all the connection will send. The same run in Cat 5e would max out at full gigabit if correctly wired.

Cat 3 typically only uses 2 pairs, Cat 5e must have 4 pairs [the shielding is also different.] Cat 3 these days is really only used as telephone cabling, not ethernet.